# AngularJS directive create empty array in scope.

Tags: angularjs

I have created one directive and use scope variables in this way:

```
<div data-create-instants-since-beginning data-daysnum="daysnum" data-tostore="tostore">
```

I want when tostore is undefined to set it to empty array but unfortunately this not working.

```
.directive("createInstantsSinceBeginning", function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                daysnum: "=",
                tostore: "="
            },
            link: function ($scope, element) {
                if (typeof $scope.tostore == 'undefined') {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.tostore = [];
                    });
                }
    // other code ..
```

How I can solve the problem?

Best regards.

Comment: Why don't you just initialize it in your controller as you are using 2-way binding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking out the `$scope.apply`

```
.directive("createInstantsSinceBeginning", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      daysnum: "=",
      tostore: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      if (typeof scope.tostore == 'undefined') {
        scope.tostore = [];
      }
    }
  };
});
```

See working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OVsKcDebdNhxgCfdig4q?p=preview

Comment: Man you are the best :). Save me a lot of researching :).

Comment: No problem. You only need to use `$apply` when you are doing outside of angular's context. This is not one of those times.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in the directive's controller:

```
app.directive('createInstantsSinceBeginning',function(){
        return {
            scope: {
                daysnum: "=",
                tostore: "="
            },
            controller: function($scope){
                if (  $scope.tostore === undefined ) 
                    $scope.tostore = [];

            }
 }});
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way:

```
.directive("createInstantsSinceBeginning", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            daysnum: "=",
            tostore: "="
        },
        link: function ($scope, element) {
            $scope.tostore = $scope.tostore || [];
        }
// other code ..
```